# How to load child collection in linq2Db?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql, linq2db

I have created below tables in my sql.

```
create table Department
(
    Id uniqueidentifier primary key not null,
    Name nvarchar(255),
    IsActive bit
)

create table Employee
(
    Id uniqueidentifier primary key not null,
    Name nvarchar(255),
    Age int,
    Address nvarchar(255),
    Email varchar(max),
    Dob datetime,
    DeptId uniqueidentifier,
    IsActive bit,
    Foreign key (DeptId) references Department(Id)
)
```

In employee table, "DeptId" is foreign key.
I have written the code to fetch all the employees with its department.

**The problem here is I am getting the employees with null departments**.
I remember when using EF core, I did something like this:

```
 var employees = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Department);
```

The above code returns employees with it departments but when using linq2Db, How do I write the code to fetch employees with departments ?

Here is my code: 
**Employee.cs**

```
    public class Employee
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? Age { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Dob { get; set; }
        public Guid? DeptId { get; set; }
        public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }
```

**Department.cs**

```
    public class Department
    {
        public Department()
        {
            this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
        }

        [PrimaryKey]
        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

        [Association(ThisKey = nameof(Department.Id), OtherKey = nameof(Employee.DeptId))]
        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
```

**SampleDbContext.cs**

```
    public class SampleDbContext : DataConnection
    {
        public SampleDbContext(LinqToDbConnectionOptions<SampleDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        public ITable<Employee> Employees => GetTable<Employee>();
        public ITable<Department> Departments => GetTable<Department>();
    }
```

**EmployeeController.cs**

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly SampleDbContext _sampleDbContext;

        public EmployeeController(SampleDbContext sampleDbContext)
        {
            _sampleDbContext = sampleDbContext;
        }

        // GET: api/<EmployeeController>
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<Employee[]> Get()
        {
            return await _sampleDbContext.Employees.ToArrayAsync();
        }

    }
```

Can anybody help me on this ?
Thanks !!

Comment: See following for sample : https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/blob/master/Tests/Linq/Samples/JoinOperatorTests.cs

Comment: I just checked and found a query selector there. Did you mean to say that . Include () in EF performs inner join behind the scene ?

Comment: Yes.  The linq query is translated to a database query.

Comment: Alright!! But does linq2db has anything equivalent to .Include() ? Is there any better way to write this code ?

Comment: Yes, it does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150864/linq2db-effective-way-to-query-hierarchy-of-objects

Comment: I tried this "_sampleDbContext.Employees.LoadWith(d => d.Department).ToArrayAsync();" and now it is giving me an error called "LinqToDBException: Member 'd.Department' is not an association.".  What is wrong I am doing here ?

Comment: In the link I've described that Association attribute is needed.

Comment: Yes I have added the Association. In "Department.cs" I have added this "[Association(ThisKey = nameof(Department.Id), OtherKey = nameof(Employee.DeptId))]" on public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }. But still the same error "LinqToDBException: Member 'dep.Department' is not an association." In my controller, I am doing this " _sampleDbContext.Employees.LoadWith(dep => dep.Department).ToArrayAsync();" . Do you think that something wrong is happening here ?

Comment: Better to create issue on GitHub. I'll check what is wrong.

Comment: Edit your question and add Association attributes.

Comment: Here is my public repo : https://github.com/Ashwani44/Linq2DbDemo

Comment: I updated my question and added that Association attribute.