# Entity Framework Linq2Db Translation

Tags: entity-framework, linq2db

I am upgrading a website that used Entity Framework and now uses Linq2Db. I notice Linq2Db has no navigation properties. How would I translate this code from Entity Framework? I need to return an order with a list of order items, shipments, and other related objects. I am unable to query order items, shipments, and the other objects one by one.

```
           IQueryable<Order> query = GetExpandedOrderTable();
            DateTime beginTime = settings.LastDownloadUtc;
            DateTime endTime = settings.LastDownloadUtcEnd;

            query = query.Where(a => a.CreatedOnUtc >= beginTime);
            query = query.Where(a => a.CreatedOnUtc <= endTime);

            List<int> storeIds = GetStoreIds();

            if (storeIds.Count() > 0)
                query = query.Where(a => storeIds.Contains(a.StoreId));

            return new PagedList<Order>(query, 0, 1000).ToList();


    /// <summary>
    /// Expands order items and other sub properties.
    /// Increases performance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IQueryable<Order> GetExpandedOrderTable()
    {
        return orderRepository.Table
            .Include(a => a.OrderItems)
            .Include("OrderItems.Product")
            .Include(a => a.OrderNotes)
            .Include(a => a.GiftCardUsageHistory)
            .Include(a => a.BillingAddress)
            .Include(a => a.BillingAddress.StateProvince)
            .Include(a => a.BillingAddress.Country)
            .Include(a => a.ShippingAddress)
            .Include(a => a.ShippingAddress.StateProvince)
            .Include(a => a.ShippingAddress.Country)
            .Include(a => a.Customer)
            .Include(a => a.DiscountUsageHistory)
            .Include(a => a.Shipments);
    }`
```

Comment: Why linq2db does not have navigation properties? It has associations. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63267282/10646316

Answer (score 1):

EF Navigation Property => linq2db Association

EF Eager Loading Include() => linq2db [LoadWith()](https://linq2db.github.io/api/LinqToDB.LinqExtensions.html#LinqToDB_LinqExtensions_LoadWith__2_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___)